# Better approach for having two or more threads listening on same port

Tags: multithreading, sockets, network-programming

Dears,

I'm currently working on a network server application. I plan to have one thread for each server's core handling clients connections in order to do a better use of server's resources and get faster responses, avoid blocking, etc.

From what I know, there are two ways of doing it:

1) parent process opens listening socket and each thread monitors it (epoll, kqueue, etc.) for new connections and `accept()` them;

2) each thread opens its own listener socket on same port and address (possible thanks to SO_REUSEPORT and SO_REUSEADDR), monitor it for new connections and `accept()` them.

I'm not sure about how it works behind the scenes, but I suppose doing it like #2 will delegate to kernel networking section the task of distributing client connections over threads. Is it correct?

Is there any significant difference between two approaches? Is there something that can go wrong in a way of doing it whereas it doesn't happens in other? Will I get better results (less resources usage, less latency, etc.) doing it in some specific way instead of another?

I think only way to see some difference between two approaches by comparison is generating a huge amount of connections, but my poor computer can't deal with it. So I fall back on your experience and knowledge to get an answer for this question. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) parent process opens listening socket and each thread monitors it (epoll, kqueue, etc.) for new connections and accept() them;

You can do that, but there's not a lot of benefit over having a single `accept()` thread and a thread pool. And you will have races between the accepting threads that only one of them will win at a time (the 'thundering herd' problem).

> 2) each thread opens its own listener socket on same port and address (possible thanks to SO_REUSEPORT and SO_REUSEADDR), monitor it for new connections and `accept()` them.

You can't do this with TCP unless you are on Windows, where the semantics as far as I can tell are undefined.

Comment: I'm confused about thundering herd problem, as some people say it has been fixed in earlier versions of Linux kernel (nothing about BSD's one). It also looks like it's possible to work around it using semaphores. //// About #2: so, what is the purpose of SO_REUSEPORT and SO_REUSEADDR on Linux/BSD if not allow more than one listener socket on same port and address?

Comment: The thundering herd problem will arise within your code, not within the Linux kernel. All the selectors will fire; all your threads will call `accept()`; and all but one of them will get -1 with `errno == EAGAIN`. SO_REUSEPORT is for multicast, and SO_REUSEADDR only has one use for TCP, and this isn't it.

Comment: The thundering herd problem fix I read about was some change in Linux kernel that causes only one process/thread `accept()`ing being notified about new connection. I'm not sure it has been implemented however, so will not rely on that, even because I intend to have my application running on FreeBSD.

Comment: That applies to blocking mode. You stated you were using `select()` or `poll()`, which implies non-blocking mode.

Comment: I don't believe @EJP's response to the second solution is correct. On Linux kernels `>= 3.9`, `SO_REUSEPORT` does indeed allow multiple threads to listen on the same IP *and* port, even for TCP. In fact, [that's why it was introduced](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/).

Answer (score 1):

Here a suggestion , 
When parent thread started to listen for the request then new thread only created 
when new connection arrived and return a new socket for that request , now you can use that socket in any thread as you like , there will be no problem . 
Thank .

Comment: Your suggestion is about to do a lazy-initialization of worker threads or create a new thread for each new connection that arrived? I couldn't get it.